# Increase dimensionality for attributes using weka?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, weka

I'm working on replicating results from a paper and when the authors are describing their setup for SVM they say this:

> To increase the dimensionality of our feature vectors to be better
>   suited to SVMs, we expanded the feature space by taking the polynomial
>   combinations of degree less than or equal to 2, of all features. This
>   increased the number of features from 12 to 91.

How would you do this in the gui version of weka?

I really can't figure out what setting they changed to increase the number of attributes by 79. I've looked through the internet and through the weka documentation and even just clicking around on the gui but I can't seem to find any functionality that would do this.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems the authors of the paper do not really understand how SVM works. Simply train SVM with polynomial kernel of degree 2 and you will get the same expressive power.